# Google Sheets formula for "if 1: select A, if 2: concat A and B, else leave blank"

Tags: google-sheets

This is an updated question to a previous one I had. I realized I had left a very important part out when submitting the last one because I was so hung up on trying to concatenate A and B.

I'm working with a sheet that has a column of names and their rows signal 1, 2, or 0 for 'coming', 'unsure', or 'not coming'. The idea was that by filling in the 0's, 1's and 2's this would translate to a visible table below that printed their names if coming, or printed their names with question marks if unsure and blank if not coming. I had thought to make a column of question marks and if c = 2, concat the name with the mark and print it. Alas, I have had no such luck getting any kind of combination of formulas to work. So I turn to you stack masters. [Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBhEK.png)

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(C2:E8*1=2, A2:A8&B2:B8, IF(C2:E8*1=1, A2:A8, )))
```

[image]

or more compact:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(
 IF(C2:E8*1=2, A2:A8&B2:B8&"×", IF(C2:E8*1=1, A2:A8&"×", )),,9^9)), "×"))))
```

[image]